# How to encode labels for for ordered categorical target? Is there an algorithm for this type of problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, ordered-logit

I have a classification problem, with a target categorical variable. Is a string variable that  involves some sort of classification: good, medium and bad.

Is there some algorithm or technique (involving ordinal label encoding, for example) that takes advantage of the 'sorted' target? Could it be an approach to convert de target to integer with ordinal encoding, use a regression algorithm, and later 'round' the results to get the categorical predictions?

Comment: The term of art you're looking for is [tag:ordered-logit]

Comment: It is unclear if this question is about converting a string variable to an ordinal variable (using numeric values to represent the ordering) or if it is about predicting an ordinal variable via regression techniques...please clarify.

Comment: @GreggH I have a categorical string variable. Text variable. Three values: goog, medium, bad. For a prediction, I can use it just as categorial, may be even use a dummy encoding (OneHotEncoding). But theese categories involve some ORDER. My question is if you recommend some algorythm or aproach to take advantage of it, that they are not unrelated categories, but ORDERED categories.

Answer (score 0):

A dummy variable coding strategy for ordinal data is to model the incremental increase from each category to the next.  In this context, this can be accomplished with the following dummy variables:

- d_m = 1 if good or medium (0 otherwise)
- d_g = 1 if good (0 otherwise)

If you run the regression with these two predictors, it will model the ordinal structure of the categorical variable.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! :)